# Get correct dispatch type using ConnectedProps with redux-thunk

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

As per title, i'm using Redux-Toolkit & Typescript. In particular, I'm trying to use ConnectedProps as suggested in the [redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically). Unfortunately, it seems to not get the type of dispatch right (in particular, it considers it to have the normal Dispatch type rather than a ThunkDispatch).

Any suggestions? At the moment I am either:

(1) Using a custom 'useThunkDispatch' hook. But this introduces an extra line + import I don't really want.

(2) Using the function version of 'mapDispatch', explicitly typing my dispatch as a ThunkDispatch (or AppDispatch as seen in the [redux toolkit docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript/#getting-the-dispatch-type)

**Code Sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/connectedprops-typing-for-thunk-uyplw

Comment: Can you post some additional code + info as to where and how it's "not getting the type of `dispatch` right"?  (Ideally a CodeSandbox that demonstrates the compilation error.)  If you're using `mapDispatch` + `ConnectedProps<T>`, the point is you shouldn't even have any references to `dispatch` by itself - it's just binding action creators for you as props.

Comment: @markerikson Updated above to include CodeSandBox!

Yes, agreed with regards to mapDispatch, however two issues:

(1) It seems I have to explicitly use the functional form and cast the Dispatch to ThunkDispatch, else normal dispatch is inferred and mapped Thunks have typescript errors. According to redux docs i should use object form, but it seems not possible in this example.


(2) I actually prefer not using mapDispatch - I like very explicitly seeing in my code what is redux related and what is state related. I know it goes against redux style recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, the explicit use of `dispatch` coming from `connect` is actually the issue here.

Because your Redux store is defined separately from the React components that use the store, they have no way of knowing what customizations you *might* have used when you created the store.  For TS specifically, `connect` has no way to know that your store has the thunk middleware applied, and thus should be typing the `dispatch` prop as `ThunkDispatch` instead of `Dispatch`.

That's one of the reasons why we strongly recommend the use of [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object) with `connect`, because then your component never has to know the difference.

If you truly want to explicitly reference `dispatch` in your component, you have a couple different options:

- Switch to using [the React-Redux hooks API](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) and [declare the type of `dispatch` as received from `useDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#typing-the-usedispatch-hook)
- Use [the function form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-a-function) with `connect`, and explicitly declare the type of `dispatch` as the argument

Personally, I'd recommend going with hooks.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations Mark. I've updated the CodeSandbox a little to have three components, which use connect / hook / mapDispatch-based dispatches respectively. From what I can tell, object-based mapDispatch completely forgoes type-safety - I can even feed it a function with no 'type' attribute and it doesn't complain! Perhaps this doesn't matter - as discussed on GitHub, we always use imported actions anyway... Hooks on the other hand do a great job - they correctly pick out the actions that aren't in the Union type. Interested to hear your thoughts on mapDispatch "shortcomings"?