# Improper type signature for `dispatch` method despite using "app dispatch" hook

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit, thunk

## Introduction

I'm using [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) to add Redux support to a React application served by a Django app. We're using Typescript, and so we're following the [Typescript Quick Start](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript) from the Redux Toolkit docs.

An important element of using Redux (Toolkit?) with Typescript is to ensure that your `dispatch(...)` method has the correct type signature. As described in [the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-typed-hooks), if you simply use the `useDispatch(...)` hook from react-redux,

> the default `Dispatch` type does not know about thunks. In order to correctly dispatch thunks, you need to use the specific customized `AppDispatch` type from the store that includes the thunk middleware types, and use that with `useDispatch`. Adding a pre-typed `useDispatch` hook keeps you from forgetting to import `AppDispatch` where it's needed.

That's fine, and I followed those instructions. My code exports a new hook, just like the tutorial:

```js
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
```

My problem is: when I use that hook, the type signature for the `dispatch(...)` method still doesn't accept thunks. The following code:

```js
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
dispatch(customAction({ ... params ... }));
```

Produces a compilation error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/Widget.tsx:45:9 
TS2345: Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<void, CustomActionParams, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<void, CustomActionParams, {}>' but required in type 'AnyAction'.
```

My question: **Why isn't the typed dispatch method correctly accepting `AsyncThunkAction`s?**

## Things I've Tried

Interestingly, calling `dispatch(...)` with the `AppDispatch` type explicitly parameterized results in the same error. Only parameterizing `dispatch(...)` with `any` silences the error, which obviously isn't ideal.

```js
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
dispatch<AppDispatch>(customAction({ ... params ... })); // same error
dispatch<any>(customAction({ ... params ... })); // error silenced
```

This makes me think that the issue is `AppDispatch` not correctly inferring that it should take `AsyncThunkAction` types, which should happen automatically. Something that could be causing this is that my async action is defined [within `extraReducers`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#extrareducers), like so:

```js
export const customAction = createAsyncThunk(
    "slice/customAction",
    async (payload: CustomActionParams) { ... }
);

export const slice = createSlice({
    name: "slice",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
         builder.addCase(customAction.fulfilled, (state, action) => { ... });
    }
});
```

I'm not sure why this wouldn't cause the type to update, but it's something I've got to resolve.

## Differences from standard setup

A few things about my environment could also theoretically contribute to this issue, so I'm including them here for correctness:

- This React application is *not* a single page application, but is embedded in a rendered Django template by using [django-react-templatetags](https://github.com/Frojd/django-react-templatetags). This library automatically injects script tags inline to pass component props and initialize components using `ReactDOM`. See [this page](https://github.com/Frojd/django-react-templatetags/blob/develop/docs/getting-started.md#connecting-view-and-template) for an example on how this works.

  - This means that each component has its own [`<Provider>` component](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider), instead of one `<Provider>` at the root, but all share the same store.
- The `useAppDispatch(...)` custom method is defined in my store file (`store.ts`) rather than a `hooks.ts` at the root, but that shouldn't cause any issues.
- **Edit:** All of this is in a [Yarn 2 Workspace](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces), rather than the root directory of a package.

## Questions that are *not* duplicates:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67059061/) uses an incorrect definition for `useAppDispatch(...)`. I'm using the correct definition in my code.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60941016/) doesn't use a custom dispatch hook.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62318322/) uses incorrect and overspecified types for the `dispatch` method of the `thunkAPI` object in the [`payloadCreator` method of `createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator), which I don't currently use. I'm trying to use `dispatch` as imported via hook in a component, not in my `payloadCreator` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was ultimately caused by some sort of version mismatch between the `react-redux` and `@reduxjs/toolkit` packages. I removed my `yarn.lock` and deleted my `node_modules`, and reinstalled from scratch, and the issue disappeared!

(Additionally, I also had to pin TypeScript at `~4.1.5` due to [a separate issue installing TypeScript with Yarn 2](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/2514).)